# Qual é o significado de «Negócio da china»?

Tags: significado, expressões, origem-histórica

O que significa **Negócio da China** e por que **Negócio da China**?

Pelo o que percebi pelo texto e procurei na internet, está dizendo que é uma oportunidade boa? Sim?

Quais outros significados pode ter? Também por que China? Tem uma história?

Exemplo:

> O preço é ótimo. A gente vai fazer um negócio da China!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Negócio da China*** significa ’negócio muito lucrativo ou vantajoso’, como se pode ver nos dicionários [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/neg%C3%B3cio) e [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/neg%C3%B3cio/). Portanto se comprares por exemplo, um bom carro usado por um preço muito baixo, podes dizer que fizeste um negócio da china.

É uma expressão muito antiga. Já aprece, por exemplo, neste [artigo em 1839](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=302619&pesq=neg%C3%B3cio%20china&pasta=ano%20183). Este [outro de 1833](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=702110&pesq=neg%C3%B3cio%20china&pasta=ano%20183) relaciona “negócio na China” com “negócio de Macau”, e diz que *negócio de Macau* é um “rifão” (expressão idiomática) antigo. Portanto parece, que antes de se dizer *negócio da China*, se dizia *negócio de Macau*. Macau era um antigo entreposto comercial português na China (ao pé de Hong Kong), e fazia-se lá um comércio muito lucrativo. Este [Diário da Câmara de Deputados de 1828](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ZMNOAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA64-PA3&lpg=RA64-PA3&dq=%22melhor%20que%20o%20negocio%20de%20macau%22&source=bl&ots=uc16A57mkF&sig=ACfU3U2nkKIu73FT7_SIlRPHzNYtBujt-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTsvnYqdfkAhVOBWMBHSygCvQQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22melhor%20que%20o%20negocio%20de%20macau%22&f=false) diz (grafia atualizada):

> Isto é melhor que o negócio de Macau, 450$ réis [antiga moeda portuguesa e brasileira] por 200 exemplares, e fica ele com o resto da impressão toda para vender, é cousa [mesmo que *coisa*] espantosa;